# MariaDB connection closes randomly

Tags: mariadb, velocity

So I wanted to create a plugin for my velocity proxy and I wanted to create a connection to my mariaDB database but the connection keeps closing. I actually removed the generation of the rank and user table in my Main class for debug but I can assure that the tables are setup correctly.

Here is my connection class:

```
public class MySQLDatabase {
    private Connection connection;

    public MySQLDatabase(String host, int port, String database, String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        String url = "jdbc:mariadb://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database;
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        if(connection != null && !connection.isClosed())
            Main.logger.info(Constants.PREFIX + "§7Connected to the database!");
    }


    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }


    public boolean isConnected() {
        try {
            return connection != null && !connection.isClosed();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void closeConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
            connection.close();
            Main.logger.info(Constants.PREFIX + "§7Database connection closed!");
        }
    }
}
```

This class:

```
public class DataManager {

    private MySQLDatabase database;

    private Gson gson;

    public DataManager(MySQLDatabase database, Gson gson) {
        this.database = database;
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    public void saveRank(String name, String prefix, String suffix, List<String> permissions) throws SQLException {
        Main.logger.info(Constants.PREFIX + "§7Saving group §6" + name + " §7to database...");
        String query = "INSERT INTO ranks (name, prefix, suffix, permissions) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try (Connection connection = database.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            statement.setString(1, name);
            statement.setString(2, prefix);
            statement.setString(3, suffix);
            statement.setString(4, String.join(",", permissions));
            statement.executeUpdate();
        }
        Main.logger.info(Constants.PREFIX + "§7Group §6" + name + " §7saved to database!");
    }


    public void saveUser(UUID uuid, String name, String group) throws SQLException {
        String query = "INSERT INTO users (uuid, name, `group`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        try (Connection connection = database.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            statement.setString(1, uuid.toString());
            statement.setString(2, name);
            statement.setString(3, group);
            statement.executeUpdate();
        }
    }

    public User loadUser(String name) throws SQLException {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?";
        try (Connection connection = database.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            statement.setString(1, name);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(resultSet.getString("uuid"));
                    String group = resultSet.getString("group");
                    return new User(uuid, name, group);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Rank getRank(String name) throws SQLException {
        Main.logger.info(Constants.PREFIX + "§7Loading group §6" + name + "§7...");
        String query = "SELECT * FROM ranks WHERE name = ?";
        try (Connection connection = database.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            statement.setString(1, name);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    String prefix = resultSet.getString("prefix");
                    String suffix = resultSet.getString("suffix");
                    String permissionsJson = resultSet.getString("permissions");
                    List<String> permissions = gson.fromJson(permissionsJson, new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType());
                    Main.logger.info(Constants.PREFIX + "§7Group §6" + name + " §7loaded!");
                    return new Rank(name, prefix, suffix, permissions);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public User getUser(String name) throws SQLException {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ?";
        try (Connection connection = database.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            statement.setString(1, name);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(resultSet.getString("uuid"));
                    String group = resultSet.getString("group");
                    return new User(uuid, name, group);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Should be able to save data without loosing connection to the database.

The server log:

```
[22:04:17 ERROR]: Couldn't pass ProxyInitializeEvent to urbanlife java. lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=1
06) Connection is closed
at net.urbanlife.GroupManager createGroup(GroupManager java:24) ~[?:?]
at net.urbanlife.Main.onProxyInitializeEvent (Main.java:59) ~[?:?]
at net.urbanlife.Lmbda$1. execute (Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at com. velocitypowered proxy event. UntargetedEventHandler$VoidHandler .la
mbdasbuildHandler$0 (UntargetedEventHandler java:47) ~[proxy.jar:3.1.2-SNAPSHOT (
git-ffa4c954-b207)]
at com.velocitypowered proxy event.VelocityEventManager fire (VelocityEve
ntManager. java:598) ~[proxy.jar:3.1.2-SNAPSHOT (git-ffa4c954-b207)]
at com.velocitypowered proxy. event.VelocityEventManager lambda$fire$5 (Ve
locityEventManager java:479) ~[proxy.jar:3.1.2-SNAPSHOT (git-ffa4c954-b207)]
at java.util.concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1136) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent. ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker .run(ThreadPoolExecutor
• Java: 635) ~[?:?]
at java. lang.Thread. run (Thread. java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=106) Connection is closed at org.mariadb. jdbc. export. ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFac

tory java:293) ~[?:?]
:370) ~[?:?]
at org.mariadb. jdbc. export.ExceptionFactory create (ExceptionFactory java
at org.mariadb. jdbc. Connection. checkNotClosed (Connection.java:658) ~[?:?
at org.mariadb.jdbc. Connection.prepareInternal (Connection.java:143) ~[?:
?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc. Connection prepareStatement (Connection•java:117) ~[?
:?]
at net.urbanlife.DataManager saveRank(DataManager java:28) ~[?:?]
at net.urbanlife.GroupManager createGroup (GroupManager •java:22) ~[?:?]
•8 more
```

Comment: Do you have the error that shows that the connection was lost that you could post on here?